# "Mark as read"-button in Claws Mail?

Tags: shortcut-keys, claws

As I prefer to manually mark my email as read, I turned of the automatic marking.

But how are you suppose to mark message as read?
In KMail I have an "Mark as read"-button in my tool-bar.

In claws I couldn't find it when editing my tool-bar, and it doesn't have a key-binding, mark as unread have one, but not mark as read??

Shortest path i found so far is: menu->m->e, but thats 3 clicks

Answer (score 1):

You can choose and set your own keybinding:

http://www.claws-mail.org/faq/index.php/Interface#How_can_I_change_the_key-bindings_.28hot-keys.29_in_Claws_Mail.3F

Comment: Include the essential part of the solution in your answer rather than just sharing the link

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the message > mark > mark as read.  That is 2 clicks.

Comment: Feels like it's slower then using the keyboard. Can't test, using Thunderbird at the moment. (almost 5 year old question).